# should i save data to static class variable or pass it to activity?

Tags: java, android, rest, class, android-activity

I have a mobile application. I am using listview in my application. I want to update my listview on my listview refresh. So should I use a static variable in model class to save refresh data? or something else?

Comment: post your code,it is easy to find solution

Answer (score 1):

Although. this question is opinion based but here is my opinion. By making this list which definitely is going to be binded with the adapter and making it `static` is really a bad idea in my opinion since it will be accessible globally. Better pass it to `Activity`.

Comment: I am using retrofit for restful web services. i need to update multiple section in my activity so what is the recommend way to pass the data?

Comment: let me explain you i am using retrofit for my webservices data. in my main activity i have 2 sections for list view. i have a music app. first listview section is for latest music and second listview for upcoming music. for now i am fetching data in splash activity and after success passing the response data to main activity listview. so the question is while i am on activity how to refresh data in activity?

Comment: As soon as your collection changes, `notifyDataChanged()` to the activity, no? This is just a random guess without seeing the actual code.

Comment: please check the screenshots i have uploaded.